# Are there any human-readable PCI slot management utilities for CentOS / Linux?

Tags: linux, pci-express, pci

I'm looking for a method to determine, in a human-readable way, what kind of PCI device is in which slot on a computer running Linux or a derivative.

`lspci` is somewhat cryptic and impenetrable, and mating that information with `dmidecode -t slot` is not possible through things like a riser card since the Bus Addresses are different.

Does anyone know of a command (built in to Linux) or a utility (open source or otherwise) that can manage PCI slots in a human readable way on a Linux based system?

Something like:

Intel NIC - Slot 2

AudioFX Soundblaster - Slot 4

Nvidia GTX770 - Slot 7

Comment: What are you trying to manage or do exactly regarding PCI?

Comment: I'm trying to print a list of PCI devices installed in my system and what slot they're in, in a human readable format. Made edits to original post.